# How can i pass from monthly data to quarterly data? R data.frame

Tags: r, database, dataframe, datetime, time-series

Hello I got something like this

I got different CIIU (later) and different Provincias, the "Time series" is "exportaciones". (Time goes from Jan 2011 to Dec 2020, there´re 11 CIIUs for each Provincia)

As you can see it's monthly data. How can I keep this data frame structure and still manage to get the quarterly data? (Sum from Jan to March, then April to June, July to September and finally October to December)

```
   CIIU                                                fecha      Provincia exportaciones
   <chr>                                               <date>     <chr>             <dbl>
 1 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-01-01 AZUAY                 0
 2 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-02-01 AZUAY                 0
 3 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-03-01 AZUAY                 0
 4 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-04-01 AZUAY                 0
 5 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-05-01 AZUAY                 0
 6 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-06-01 AZUAY                 0
 7 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-07-01 AZUAY                 0
 8 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-08-01 AZUAY                 0
 9 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-09-01 AZUAY                 0
10 Fabricación de ordenadores (computadoras) centrales 2011-10-01 AZUAY                 0
```

Comment: summarise by quarter... `lubridate` and `data.table` packages have functions for this

Comment: You don't even need a library, base R has `quarters()`

Comment: Basically create a column for quarter using `quarters(fecha)` or an analogous function, then using `library(tidyverse)`:  `group_by()` and `summarize()`

Comment: Ok, I did the new column only for quarters, but I still need the year.

Comment: You could either create a separate Year column, or use `lubridate::quarter(fecha, with_year = TRUE)`

Comment: @Mako212 wanna post it? It really worked, ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not clear exactly what the final output should look like, this is just pseudo-code. We use `lubridate::quarter` to create a grouping field with quarter and year. Then we can summarize the data to the quarter/yearly level.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>% mutate(year_quarter = lubridate::quarter(fecha, with_year = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(year_quarter, other_categories_to_summarize_by) %>%
  summarize(exportaciones = sum(exportaciones))
```